# Using groupplots for double axes plots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to plot the output of a principal component analysis. In this case, I want to group plots where I show PC1 v/s PC2, and PC1 v/s PC3.

The expected output looks something like this:
[image: Expected_Output]

And the corresponding code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%
%% PLOTSET 1
%%%
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel= PC1,
    ylabel= PC2,
    xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
    ymin=-3.0, ymax=3.0,    
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    legend columns=-1,
    legend style={
    draw=none,
    at={(0.5,-0.26)},
    anchor=center,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
    ymin=-3.0, ymax=3.0,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex, black, dashed},
    grid=major,
    grid style={dotted},
    scatter, only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,%
]
%%Insert datapoints here
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%
%% PLOTSET 2
%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel= PC1,
    ylabel= PC3,
    xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
    ymin=-3.0, ymax=3.0,    
]
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[
    legend columns=-1,
    legend style={
    draw=none,
    at={(0.5,-0.26)},
    anchor=center,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
    ymin=-3.0, ymax=3.0,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex, black, dashed},
    grid=major,
    grid style={dotted},
    scatter, only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,%
]
%%Insert datapoints here
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To make this extensible to future cases where I may have to add, say one more plot and a boxplot, or something like that, I wish to rewrite this code with `groupplot`. When I try replacing the `\begin{axis}[]` with a corresponding `\nextgroupplot[]`, I keep running into errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the double axis environment, with `groupplot` and `nextgroupplot` there is no way to do it. Also I do not think it is possible to do a double plot as a single one to repeat, if I understand right. Otherwise, if you want to use `groupplot`, you can start from something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width= 7cm, compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[ 
group style={group size=2 by 3, horizontal sep=50pt, vertical sep=50pt},
 xlabel= PC1,
ylabel= PC2,
xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
ymin=-3.0, ymax=3.0,
grid=major,
grid style={dotted},
] 

\nextgroupplot
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\nextgroupplot[ylabel=PC3]
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\nextgroupplot
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\nextgroupplot[ylabel=PC3]
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\nextgroupplot
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\nextgroupplot[ylabel=PC3]
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [>=latex, <->, black, dashed] (0,-3) -- (0,3);

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]